# Hanging Android emulators in Jenkins maven build

Tags: android, maven, android-emulator, jenkins, robotium

I am building an Android project using Jenkins, Maven and Robotium. Quite often, almost every build, a few emulators continue to run on 100% after the build fails due to failing Robotium or JUnit tests. How do I ensure that Jenkins kills the emulators after the build? The project is a multi configuration project running tests on many different Android version, resolutions and locales.

Jenkins is running on Mac OS X 10.7.4.

Thanks
Markus

Comment: Which platform are you running on?

Comment: Jenkins is running on Mac OS X 10.7.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the common emulator option to `Delete emulator after build`.